# Hadoop - map-reduce - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hadoop

The question is: if I type

hadoop jar MY.jar name_my_class /user/user/input /user/user/output

And all the class which I need are inside MY.jar, why I still get the error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ??

I know that it is very general question, so if you think is better, I 'll  provide all the details and the code :)

Thanks in advance

```
13/11/22 17:24:27 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1970405879_0001
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jocl/CLException
at jocl.MaxTemperatureReducer.setup(MaxTemperatureReducer.java:33)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:398)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jocl.CLException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 5 more
```

Comment: put full stack trace of your exception

Comment: Make sure your MapReduce code has `job.setJarByClassName(...)` where `...` is any class in the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you are missing CLException class in your class path.

Copy the jar file containing the class **org.jocl.CLException** and put it in the **lib** folder of your hadoop installation.